# Android local database

Tags: java, android, database, excel

I'm creating an app that contains movie quotes,I would like to store somewhere a file (maybe an excel file) that contains both quotes and movie genre.
The file must be local (because the app works offline for now),shold I use an xls file with the quotes in the first column and the genre in the second or should I use some sort of database?
The file is needed only when the app starts because I will load the data inside arrays

Comment: `should I use some sort of database?` **Yes**. Usually, `some sort of` is a SQLite database.

Comment: Use REALM database, much better than SQLite

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should use database in this case.

Instead of writing database manager for SQLite from scratch I would recommend to use some existing library for this purpose e.g. http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

There are also alternative libraries based on a different model e.g. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

It is up to you which library to use or maybe to write your own from scratch, but you definitely should learn how to use databases in Android development.